# A script to test for traffic from a streaming server?

Tags: linux, bash, busybox, network-traffic

I have an instrument that streams data out a tcp port, and I'd like to use standard tools in a script to determine if the stream is available.

Manually I use `ncat`, which promptly exits if the data stream isn't available.

Here's my initial bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ncat somehost 1234 >/dev/null &
pid=$!
sleep 1
if [ -d /proc/$pid/ ]; then
  kill -KILL $pid
  echo "It's alive, ALIVE\!"
  # Launch clients
else
  echo "He's dead, Jim."
  # Perform resurrection
fi
```

It works, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler or better way to accomplish this that doesn't rely on job control or procfs or even ncat.  I'd also like to know how much data was sent before a timeout exires.

And, yes, in bash `ncat host port` can be replaced by `cat </dev/tcp/host/port`, but I'd also like to avoid bash-isms (so it can work under busybox).

Another approach would be to use `wc` to count the lines/chars output by `ncat`, since it outputs only one line and exits if the connection can't be made.  But I can't wait forever for termination if the stream is up, so I'd need to use something like `timeout`, which has its own complications when trying to access the output of a command.

Is there a "plain" approach that works with minimal dependencies?

Or should I write a simple tool instead?  It would return the number of bytes read if a connection was made to host/port, a negative errno otherwise, and would support a wait time and protocol spec (tcp/udp).  A return value of 0 would mean the connection was made, but no data arrived before the wait time expired (a good thing to know).

Or maybe patch `ncat` to do the above?

Comment: Instead of `timeout` it is possible to redirect the `ncat` output to `head -n 3`, which will cause a pipe error after 3 lines (indicating an active stream).  Unfortunately, `ncat` responds poorly to `SIGPIPE`, and it is a PITA to handle signal errors in `bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [`netcat in FreeBSD`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nc), which has a `-z` option that simply checks whether a port is open.  This eliminates the background and sleep you're using in your script.

```
  -z   Specifies that nc should just scan for listening daemons, without
       sending any data to them.
```

The option exists in netcat on an old Ubuntu box here, so that might be an option for you.

```
$ nc -z somehost 1234 && echo "It's alive, ALIVE!"
```

I don't see an equivalent option in `ncat`.  You may be able to compile netcat into busybox; it's much smaller than `ncat`, at least on my systems:

Linux:

```
$ ls -lH `which nc ncat`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  31296 2010-02-21 01:32 /bin/nc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 130448 2009-11-06 04:39 /usr/bin/ncat
```

FreeBSD:

```
ls -l `which nc ncat`
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   28112 Jan 15 14:53 /usr/bin/nc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  182775 Mar 19  2012 /usr/local/bin/ncat
```

Of course, this doesn't help you check the amount of traffic that has come through the stream, or to analyse its content.  For that, I think your solution is innovative and reasonable, though the challenge you've presented may not be resolvable easily.

You can use `ps` to avoid the procfs dependency, and you can store things in a temp file for analysis rather.  Note that busybox should include a `mktemp`, but you should probably check the options.  I haven't tested this:

```
#!/bin/sh

TMPFILE=`mktemp /tmp/str.XXXX`
trap "rm -f $TMPFILE" 0 1 2 3 15

nc somehost 1234 > $TMPFILE &
pid=$!
sleep 1

if ps $pid >/dev/null; then
  kill -KILL $pid
  echo -n "It's alive, "
  if [ -s $TMPFILE ]; then
    echo "ALIVE!"
  else
    echo "but unresponsive."
  fi
else
  echo "He's dead, Jim."
fi
```

That's all I've got.  And it's not much different from what you already have.

Another option might be to build a custom tool that you might be able to compile into your own busybox, but that'll be a [c](/questions/tagged/c) question rather than a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) question.  :-)

Comment: I already have most of the C code needed for a tool, so I'll probably do that.

Comment: Using "nc -w 1 -z somehost 1234" speeds things up a bit, so long as data is expected at least once per second.

Comment: Ah yes, perfect `-w` provides both a timeout on the connection, as well as idle detection.  Glad I could help bring back a classic.  ;-)  Next up, I'll be happy to answer your [tag:awk] and [tag:sed] questions!

Comment: `ncat` can emulate `nc -z` via a dummy `-c` option (which prevents endless spewing of port traffic). The following silently sets the exit status (`$?`) to 0 for success (traffic available on port) and 1 for failure (no connection): `ncat -w 1 -c "echo" >/dev/null 2>&1`.  The redirection is needed to consume `ncat`'s failure message.

Comment: To continue my prior comment: The `-w` option works as expected, but if used with `-u` (udp) be sure to also include `-i` with the same value as `-w` (the default `-w` value is 6 seconds, though `-i` has no default).

Comment: Hmmm... Rather than invoke a shell as a do-nothing command, `-e /bin/true` should be a more efficient dummy operation than `-c "echo"`.